# What are alternatives to number theory based crypto?

Tags: number-theory, lattice-crypto

Quantum crypto,lattice based crypto, Neurocryptography and cellular automata based cryptography are alternatives to number theory based crypto. I need to know what are the other hard problems like Lattice problems and Number theory based problems that can be used for cryptography(For asymmetric crypto).

Comment: Are you talking about asymmetric encryption, or symmetric encryption? For symmetric operations almost nobody number theory based crypto.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I am talking about asymmetric crypto

Answer (score 1):

Code based cryptography like [McEliece cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem), is based on the hard problem of decoding linear codes. But i think it lies to the group of quantum based crypto since as far as we know it is still immune to quantum attacks